# Using a Javascript function in Kotlin with Arguments

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, encryption, autofill

I am working on an autofill and encryption system for Android. My autofill system is written in Kotlin, and my encryption functions are written in Javascript. I want to call a function from my Javascript to be used in my Kotlin code. I cannot figure out a way to use a javascript function with arguments from my Kotlin code

```
function encryptMP(currentPw, Masterpw){
 // js code that encrypts a pw using the masterpw
}
```

```
@JSModule
external fun encryptMP(currentpw, Masterpw)
//I would like to use this function elsewhere
val pw_encrypted = encryptMP(password, masterpassword)
```

Comment: Encryption function written in JavaScript? A very strange system design...

Comment: It is actually translated over from Dart and then given to me to incorporate. It is almost 20k lines long so rewriting it somewhere else isn't really an option